# Why wont this position properly using css?

Tags: php, html, css

This should be simple, it is just three div tags inside of another div tag.  The three div tags should just line up in a row.  Instead they are  lined up vertically.  Nothing I do seems to fix it.

```
<head>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php

function NameChange($num) {

$card = $_POST["state".$num];
$spaces = " ";
$underscore = "_";
$imagename = str_replace($spaces, $underscore, $card);

return $imagename;
}

?>




<div id="main">
<div id="3c1">
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function myPopup1() {
window.open( "images/'.NameChange(1).'.jpg", "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 691, width = 468, resizable = 0" )
}
</script>';

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function myPopup2() {
window.open( "images/'.NameChange(2).'.jpg", "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 691, width = 468, resizable = 0" )
}
</script>';

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function myPopup3() {
window.open( "images/'.NameChange(3).'.jpg", "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 691, width = 468, resizable = 0" )
}
</script>';



echo '<img src=images/'.NameChange(1).'_tn.jpg />'; 
echo "<br />";
echo '<input type="button" onClick="myPopup1()" value="Image">';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function myPopup1t() {
window.open( "/'.$_POST[state1].'.html", "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 691, width = 468, resizable = 0" )
}
</script>';
echo '<input type="button" onClick="myPopup1t()" value="Meaning">';
?>
</div>

<div id="3c2">
<?php
echo '<img src=images/'.NameChange(2).'_tn.jpg />'; 
echo "<br />";
echo '<input type="button" onClick="myPopup2()" value="Image">';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function myPopup2t() {
window.open( "/'.$_POST[state2].'.html", "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 691, width = 468, resizable = 0" )
}
</script>';
echo '<input type="button" onClick="myPopup2t()" value="Meaning">';
?>
</div>

<div id="3c3">
<?php
echo '<img src=images/'.NameChange(3).'_tn.jpg />'; 
echo "<br />";
echo '<input type="button" onClick="myPopup3()" value="Image">';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function myPopup3t() {
window.open( "/'.$_POST[state3].'.html", "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 691, width = 468, resizable = 0" )
}
</script>';
echo '<input type="button" onClick="myPopup3t()" value="Meaning">';
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And the CSS

```
#main {
    width: 808px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
#main #3c1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline;
}
#main #3c2 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline;
}
#main #3c3 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id's cannot start with numbers. You cannot set height and width (among other attributes) on inline elements. Use `display:inline-block` for that. Also use a single class if all 3 divs will have the exact same CSS rules.

Answer (score 3):

If display:inline is not doing the right thing thing you can float the divs.

```
 <div>
     <div style="float:left">stuff</div>
     <div style="float:left">stuff</div>
     <div style="float:left">stuff</div>
     <br style="clear:both;"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: He said in the question that he wants them in a row, but they're in a column instead.

Comment: Do a sanity check - assign a color to the divs in the CSS and make sure your stylesheet is actually applying correctly.

Comment: yea, sounds like you don't have a stylesheet attached

Comment: As a side note, your myPopup() functions are redundant - just write a generic one, and pass in the url you want to open.

Comment: This is odd.. if I change the main div the change works.  Any other div and it doesn't work.

Comment: * as for the side note, how do I pass it the url?

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest approach - User **[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)** in conjunction with Firefox and edit/adjust the styling using Firebug. This will give you dynamic preview and you'll get the correct styling in no time.

Agree with Michael's response though regarding ID's starting with numbers. You should fix that and check out the results.